# Can an AGIC contact an App GW in a different Azure subscription?

Tags: azure, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, gateway, azure-application-gateway

An Ingress controller that would contact an Application Gateway in another Azure Subscription. Is this even possible?

Comment: I think could be possible but the subscription need to be in same Azure AD Tenant

Answer (score 1):

> An Ingress controller that would contact an Application Gateway in another Azure Subscription. Is this even possible?

Yes , As [YK1](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1529246/yk1) said in comments it should be possible to contact another application gateway in another subscription but they should be residing under same tenant.

If they are residing under same tenant , then you can create a cross subscription vnet peering between application gateway vnet and aks vnet on different subscriptions. Then you can try to achieve the brownfield deployment for ingress on AKS.

**Reference:**

[Create a VNet peering - different subscriptions | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/create-peering-different-subscriptions)

[Create an ingress controller with an existing Application Gateway | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/ingress-controller-install-existing)